# Trying to rig eyes, but what should be the driver only spits out 0's instead of it's global axis. (I'm using a target constraint). [Videos included]

Tags: rigging

I am having an issue with the eyes of a model

I am trying to have the rotation of an empty with a tracked constraint be a driver. However, when doing so, I no longer can see the empty's global rotational axis.

[image: screenshot]

Here is a video showing the issue I'm having

https://youtu.be/LIedMhWMfhc

Also, here is a video with it baked emulating what it would be like if it were working the way I want it to.

https://youtu.be/zyQCtsnPxNY

Comment: Rather than videos, it would be more helpful if you could add a blend file to your question showing the problem ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)) and some screenshots explaining what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The *Track To* constraint does not change the Empty's global rotation. To get the rotation numbers you need to apply the *Visual Transform* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode.

But this will not help you and is not what you want. You want to use the ***UV Warp* modifier**. It will do the job. It calculates the distances between the origins of two objects and shifts the UV mapping accordingly.

So you can specify the eyeball as *Object From* and the control Empty object as *To*. If the pupil moves in the wrong direction you need to rotate the UV island or change the mapping of the *Axis U*. It's *U* =>`X` and *V* => `Z` in the example.

Example with the default cube:

[image: screenshot with modifiers]

Result:

[image: example animation]